# Querying dbpedia to get influenced and influence by for a particular artist

Tags: sparql, dbpedia

I am querying DBpedia to get all the influenced and influencedBy for a particular artist. But the query is giving me a blank result for most of the artists but is showing for some. For example, the result is blank for Andy Warhol (http://dbpedia.org/page/Andy_Warhol) but has some values for Truman Capote (http://dbpedia.org/page/Truman_Capote). I have attached my query below.

```
PREFIX rdf: <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#>
PREFIX rdfs: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#>
PREFIX daa: <http://data.americanartcollaborative.org#>
PREFIX cs: <http://purl.org/vocab/changeset/schema#>
PREFIX crm: <http://www.cidoc-crm.org/cidoc-crm/>
PREFIX crmeh: <http://purl.org/crmeh#>
PREFIX ecrm: <http://erlangen-crm.org/current/>
PREFIX ecrm: <http://erlangen-crm.org/current/>
PREFIX la_vocabs: <http://linkedarc.net/vocabs/>
PREFIX re: <http://www.w3.org/2000/10/swap/reason#>
PREFIX foaf: <http://xmlns.com/foaf/0.1/>
PREFIX fo: <http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Format#>
PREFIX dct: <http://purl.org/dc/terms/>
PREFIX dbo: <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/>
PREFIX dul: <http://www.ontologydesignpatterns.org/ont/dul/DUL.owl#>
PREFIX skos: <http://www.w3.org/2004/02/skos/core#>
PREFIX dbp: <http://dbpedia.org/property/>
PREFIX dbc: <http://dbpedia.org/resource/Category:>
PREFIX db: <http://dbpedia.org/>
PREFIX owl: <http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#>

SELECT  DISTINCT ?sub ?PersonName ?obj ?influencedPerson ?
 influencedByPerson WHERE {
 ?sub rdf:type owl:Thing.
 ?sub foaf:name ?PersonName.
 ?sub dbo:influenced ?obj.
 ?sub dbo:influencedBy ?obj.
 ?obj foaf:name ?influencedPerson.  
 ?obj foaf:name ?influencedByPerson.
 Filter regex(?PersonName, "Andy Warhol", "i" ) 
}
```

Please do let me know what is wrong with my query.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is in the data and both properties `dbo:influenced` and `dbo:influencedBy`. Indeed a person can occur in both subject or object position of a triple. And for Andy Warhol it's the case that he occurs only in the object position of triples with those relations. In DBpedia pages this is visualized by the pattern "is **PROPERTY** of", i.e. "is **dbo:influenced** of" and "is **dbo:influencedBy** of".

As a solution for Andy Warhol you have to change your query to:

```sql
SELECT  DISTINCT ?sub ?PersonName ?obj ?influencedPerson ?influencedByPerson WHERE {
 ?sub rdf:type owl:Thing.
 ?sub foaf:name ?PersonName.
 ?obj dbo:influenced ?sub.
 ?obj dbo:influencedBy ?sub.
 ?obj foaf:name ?influencedPerson.  
 ?obj foaf:name ?influencedByPerson.
 Filter regex(?PersonName, "Andy Warhol", "i" ) 
}
```

A more generic solution would be to use [SPARQL 1.1 property paths](https://www.w3.org/TR/sparql11-query/#propertypaths), in particular, a combination of the alternative(`|`) and inverse(`^`) operators:

```sql
SELECT  DISTINCT ?sub ?PersonName ?obj ?influencedPerson ?influencedByPerson WHERE {
     ?sub rdf:type owl:Thing.
     ?sub foaf:name ?PersonName.
     ?sub dbo:influenced|^dbo:influenced ?obj.
     ?sub dbo:influencedBy|^dbo:influencedBy ?obj.
     ?obj foaf:name ?influencedPerson.  
     ?obj foaf:name ?influencedByPerson.
     Filter regex(?PersonName, "Andy Warhol", "i" ) 
    }
```

Some comments:

- you have so many superfluous prefix declarations
- your query returns only a results if there are persons that influenced Andy Warhol and vice versa because you used the same variable `obj`
  (by the way that's the reason why the result is still empty)
- in addition to the previous point, you're assigning the `foaf:name` of the same resource to two different variables
- the triple pattern `?sub rdf:type owl:Thing` is semantically "useless"

I guess your query should more look like that:

```sql
SELECT  DISTINCT ?sub ?PersonName ?influencedPerson ?influencedPersonName ?influencedByPerson ?influencedByPersonName WHERE {
     ?sub foaf:name ?PersonName.
     ?sub dbo:influenced|^dbo:influencedBy ?influencedPerson.
     ?sub dbo:influencedBy|^dbo:influenced ?influencedByPerson.
     ?influencedPerson foaf:name ?influencedPersonName.  
     ?influencedByPerson foaf:name ?influencedByPersonName.
     Filter regex(?PersonName, "Andy Warhol", "i" ) 
}
```

Comment: Thanks, it solved my problem but I realized that I cannot query both influenced and influenced by at the same time.  So, I decided to query them separately.  Another issue is I am receiving more results than on the dbpedia (for example, duplications).

Comment: Indeed you get duplicates, SPARQL is just pattern matching. It's up to you to avoid this. Indeed, sometimes it'S easier to achieve this on the client side.